# Is 'addressed' a right word in the context courier/delivery?

Tags: word-request, phrase-usage

Let's say I see a courier/package lying around and want to know who it belongs to, can I ask like this

> Who is this courier/package addressed to?

Here I specifically want to find out whose name is written on the address label of the box. Will this expression convey what I intend to ask?

Comment: Does "courier/package" mean "courier package" or "courier or package"?

Comment: @user3169, it couldn't be "courier or package" because couriers are people and people are not labeled with addresses.  Methinks there's only two possible interpretations to "courier/package". (1) "a courier-delivered package" (2) "a package delivered by a courier or by some other means, such as a post office"  Reading between the lines, one might assume that user \@Dude is specifically concerned about courier packages, but decided it would make sense to broaden the scope of the question to any package with an address on it.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

**First and foremost, your original suggestion is perfectly acceptable English grammar and it's perfectly understandable.**  The package has an address.  You are asking "who is it addressed to?".  You're asking about the recipient-name-part of the labeled address.  In spoken language, there's nothing wrong about that grammatically or semantically.

**There are some other common ways of asking this.**  There are scenarios one might want to use one wording or another.  Below, I've provided some common ways of asking along with some plausible scenarios.

- **Who's [it|this|that] for?**
  *A courier has a package in hand and says, "I have a package for this address." It's obvious the object in question is a **package** so you don't have to use that word.*
- **Who's package is [it|this|that]?**
  *You're a manager, and some people are looking-at/handling a package inquisitively. You want to find out what's going on and make sure the situation is handled properly.*
- **Who's [this|that] package for?**
  *You're a manager of the mail department and you notice a package on a desk, far from you, or near some letters.  One of your clerks is near the package.*
- **Who's this package addressed to?**
  *Presumably, you're close to the package. There must be some reason you're asking, even though you could just pick it up and read it yourself.  Perhaps someone else has the label.  Perhaps you don't have your glasses and you cannot read the label.*
- **Who does [this|that] package go to?**
  *"Go to" is a synonym for "recipient".  But "go to" can be interpreted more broadly, or connote that you are want to facilitate the action of routing the package.*
- **Who does [this|that] go to?**
  *If the context makes "the package" as the obvious subject, the word "package" is not required.

### THIS VS. THAT

Note that the use of ***this vs. that*** is a separate issue. (Credit to @Carsmack for noting this.)  There are various scenarios in which either *this* or *that* would be preferable. (Credit to @ColleenV for pointing this out.) There are some simple guidelines for using ***this vs. that***, but in the dynamic realm of spoken language, there are scenarios which can override these rules.  It's not always as simple as whether or not the package is within your reach.

Comment: I don't know that I would encourage someone to _always_ use "that package" even though it is correct in this particular context. I think that there are some assumptions about the situation that might not be obvious to a learner. If for example, you are sorting packages with someone else and the just handed the package to you, you would say "Who is this package for?" _This_ versus _that_ is a entirely different question, I know. I'm just biased against the word "always" :)

Comment: I find many English questions are more complex than they appear at first. I guess that's what happens when a language [borrows](http://www.quotes.net/quote/49698 "Booker T. Washington quote") so liberally from other languages.

Comment: @ColleenV, The answer to this is actually very simple: The OP's sentence was correct.  Simple!  I simplified my own answer and cleaned up (removed) my prior comment to yours since it's no longer applicable.  That orphans the context of your comment a little bit, but your point is still valid and stands on it's own.

Comment: The journey to the simpler answer was as interesting as the answer though :) My favorite part of participating in ELL is having to really think through what I know is correct so I can explain it well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd ask...

> What is the delivery address?

If you 'address to' someone, it means you are answering or quoting them. *Address to* in **this particular context** is quite uncommon, at least to my ears.

If you want to be specific about whose name is written on the package for delivery...one of them is what I'd choose...

> Whose courier/package is this? **or** 
>  Who is the recipient? **or** 
>  What is the recipient's address (on it)?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree your "address to" comment. It seems you're taking "address to" out of context by using another definition. "I need to address a concern with MaulikV." would be appropriate use for this comment, for example.  The OP's statement, "Who is this addressed to?" is grammatically correct English and sounds fine to me (native AmEng).  I wouldn't say that the form it's uncommon either.  The idea that a package has an address, and that one wants to identify the recipient-part of that address with "who" is fine.

Answer (score -1):

In conversational English, your question is fine.

Technically/pedantically, you should ask:

> "To whom is this package addressed?"

... because you are not supposed to end sentences with prepositions.

Comment: Ending sentences with prepositions is OK, even in very formal Standard English.  As you point out, "whom" is correct in this situation.  On the other hand, use of "whom" is no longer natural in American English.

Comment: I upvoted just to counter the downvote, but I'd recommend replacing "technically" with "technically/pedantically". I'm just sayin'. The prohibition against ending with prepositions is so massively ignored (at least in AmE) that its observation is usually construed as a mark of an overly fussy mind. You can, of course, refer to yourself as overly fussy and proud of it, but this is clearly a minority viewpoint. See Churchill's famous "up with which I will not put."